# Javascript/Nativescript/Node.JS. Как напистаь multiuploader файлов с отображением количества отправленных байт?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fileupload, progress-bar, nativescript

Есть multiuploader файлов с прогрессом количества загруженных файлов.. 
т.е. 1й файл из 5 загрузился - показали.. 2ой файл загрузился - показали и тд.
НО, когда файлы весят по 10 мб и более, то прогресс долго стоит на нуле.

И вот: как приделать показ количества отправленных на сервер байт каждого файла?

Можно ли вообще только на клиенте получить(узнать) что, например отправлено  300кб из 10 мегабайтного файла и отобразить это сразу?

Или как еще можно??

Просто, если сервер сторонний .. то будет невозможно реализовать логику разбиения файла по частям и склеивания его на сервере..

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите сделать это все на клиенте, то вот полезные ссылки: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698055/input-file-upload-success

https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-onprogress

Если захотите уведомлять клиент о процессах на серваке, прийдётся использовать сокеты или другие костыли.
Можно заюзать формидабл и сокет, как тут в примере: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323291/node-formidable-and-a-simple-progress-bar
Для создания события успешной передачи целого файла можно использовать событие on file:

```
var fileCounter = 0;
form.on('file', function (field, file) {
                if (file.size > 0) {
                    fileCounter++;
                    fs.rename(file.path, form.uploadDir + "/" + req.user.id + ".jpg");
                    io.sockets.emit('fileUpload', 'file uploaded ' + fileCounter);
                }
            });
```

Так же, если уведомлять конкретного клиента, надо предусмотреть механизм аутентификации, так как по-умолчанию сервак не будет видеть, какому конкретно соединению отправлять уведомление. Тогда надо в промежуточной базе данных сессий аутентификации хранить данные сессии (пользователя), там же можно хранить и текущие id сокетов именно этого клиента.

Comment: В вашем случае, постарался бы сделать все на клиенте и не лез бы на сервак.